# Move folders modified a day prior 6.30 p.m

Tags: command-line, scripts

I need to move folders which are modified a day prior 6.30 p.m. For example. The folders which are modified in Day 1 before 6.30 p.m should be moved to another folder. Please help me.

Regards,
Syed

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking, however you may want to take a look at `find` with the `-newermt` predicate e.g. `find path/to/folder -type d -newermt '6:30pm yesterday' ! -newermt '6:30pm today -exec mv -t path/to/anotherfolder/ {} + `

Answer (score 0):

```
timestamp=$(date -d "18:30 yesterday" +%s)
stat -c "%Y %n" * | while IFS= read -r mtime filename; do
    if (( mtime < timestamp )); then
        mv "$filename" /some/folder
    fi
done
```

Comment: This will break for any filename that contains a newline, but spaces in the filename should not be a problem

Comment: This answer would be better with a bit more explanation. While it may technically answer the question it's usually better to include some explanation so that people who might not be as well-versed in shell scripting are able to see/understand what's going on.